# Pair up rows in Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Player` table with 3 columns id, name, wins (number of win matches). To make a Swiss pairing where two players having near wins would play together in next round, I sort this table order by wins. How can I return a table with 4 columns id1, name1, id2, name2 such that each row of new table is the pair of rows in Players table. I can do it in python language, but I want to know that there is any query in SQL which could implement this task?

For example:

`Player` table

```
Id  Name    Wins
-----------------
1     A      3
2     B      1
3     C      4
4     D      0
```

I want to return

```
Id   Name   Id   Name
---------------------
3     C      1    A
2     B      4    D
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is certainly no easy way to do this. I don't think there's a hard way either.

Comment: i edited your question to easier readable form ... but 1 question. your desire output result ... 2nd row's id 2 name A ... is that should be B ?

Comment: Your post currently reads more like a to-do than a question. Could you please include any attempts, research, etc, as well as a small repro of your scenario? (It also may help to include the rdbms you're using as a tag.)

Comment: Do you want to pair players with highest wins with each other? What is the rdbms?

Comment: I have edited it. When we sort the table according to wins, we could group two adjacent rows together for the next round. Like code in python:

Comment: @TuanNg, do you care to answer questions? What is the rdbms?

Comment: Sorry. I have problem with internet connection.
Here is my python code to to this:
results = cursor.fetchall()   (this stores sorted table)
    i = 0
    output = []
    while(i<len(result)):
        output.append((results[i][0],results[i][1],results[i+1][0],results[i+1][1]))
        i = i+2

Comment: You have tagged `sql` not `python`. If you want to pair it up in SQL, then why are you giving the `python` code. JUST mention the database you are using. Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL,DB2??

Comment: I use PostgreSQL. I want to know that there is any query in SQL which can implement like the code in python.

Comment: Edit clarifications into your question, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
with cte as(select *, ceiling(1.0 * row_number() over(order by Wins, Id) / 2) as rn 
             from Player)
select c1.Id, c1.Name, c2.Id, c2.name
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn and c1.Id > c2.Id;
```

The idea is to rank pairs of player with the same number. So when you are ordering rows by wins you get 1, 2, 3, 4 as rank. Then you are multiply those by 1.0 just to make it numeric 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0. Then divide by 2: 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2. Then ceiling to the nearest integer: 1, 1, 2, 2. After this it is a simple self join.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d65be/2

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH ranked_players AS 
    (SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wins) rank
    FROM Player)
SELECT player1.Id, player1.Name, player2.Id, player2.Name
    FROM ranked_players as player1
    JOIN ranked_players as player2
        ON player1.rank=player2.rank-1
    WHERE player1.rank % 2 = 1
```

Sorry, I have no Postgres at hand to test.